# Laravel localization with url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-localization

I am developing a multi-language web app using Laravel framework. So in this app, I have a special condition to do multi-language feature as below.

- a user can select from some flags and change the language manually. 
  It changes his URL to /{lang} .. so, for example, webapp.com/cs - so he will see everything that in Czech language. webapp.com/en - see everything in English.
- Chosen localization should be persistent so would not disappear when user change page or something - it should always be in the URL.

I created Route to set locale in session as follows.

```
    Route::get('/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    session()->put('locale', $locale);
    return back();
  });
```

And created middleware and added it to $middlewareGroups in the http\Kernel as well.

Below is my middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (session()->has('locale')) {
            app()->setLocale(session('locale'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Localization is going well and it gives correct translations and everything. But what I need is to show in the URL what is the language is. as example webapp.com/cs,webapp.com/en. It would be great if anyone can help me with this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: so do you want to add your lang in your url??

Comment: @MaulikShah yes.

Comment: This will help you : https://medium.com/@Oriechinedu/laravel-localization-made-simple-8ee4a34731e7

Comment: Used https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization plugin and it did all I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

In your every route you can append current local language like this

```
Route::get('/home/'.app()->getLocale(),'HomeController@index');
```

and one more thing you should see this

[Laravel app()->getLocale() inside routes always print the default "en"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938230/laravel-app-getlocale-inside-routes-always-print-the-default-en)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The link you provided, guided me to the correct answer. which is about mcamara/laravel-localization plugin. Thanks