# How do I go about localizing route URIs?

Tags: laravel

Let's say I want to translate my web app into multiple languages. How would I go about localizing the route URIs?

So let's say I have a "/register" route. But if you were on the French version of the app, I'd want that route URI to be "/enregistrer". How would I go about that?

Comment: it might be easier to [use prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55573225) rather than registering multiple routes.

Comment: if you were looking for a package that can do that: https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization#translated-routes

Comment: I think the prefix solution will work @BagusTesa